# Нахождения числа вхождения одиннаковых строк в списке(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня был изначально такой список.

```
array = ['Саша','Олег','Саша','Саша','Костя','Костя','Олег','Саша']
```

Надо было найти сколь раз встречается каждый уникальный элемент в нем . С этой задачей я справился так

```
array_d = dict.fromkeys(array, 0)
for a in array:
    array_d[a] += 1
strings = []
for key,item in array_d.items():
    strings.append("{}: {}".format(key.capitalize(), item))
result = "\n".join(strings)
print(result)
```

В результате получал

```
Саша: 4
Олег: 2
Костя: 2
```

Список получал выборкой из базы данных. В результате запроса возращался полный список записей за все время.
Теперь хотелось бы разбить этот список по дням. Чтобы получить статистику по каждому дню(знаю что можно указывать в запросе к бд конкретную дату и по ней отбирать. но хотелось бы получить за 1 запрос все данные и потом разбить их по дням).
Добавил в запросе чтобы в список добавлялись и даты. Теперь получаю такой список

```
array1 = [
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 37), 'Саша'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 28, 16, 2), 'Олег'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 40), 'Саша'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 41), 'Саша'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Костя'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Костя'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Олег'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Саша']
]
```

как теперь можно получить из него список по дням?
в результате хочу получить Ж

```
2020-10-27
Саша: 4
Олег: 1
Костя: 2

2020-10-28
Олег: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использование:

- `defaultdict` -- для группировки юзеров по дате. Ключом будет дата, а значением список
- `Counter` -- для подсчета количества элементов. Ключом будет элемент, а значением количество

Пример:

```
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

array1 = [
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 37), 'Саша'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 28, 16, 2), 'Олег'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 40), 'Саша'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 41), 'Саша'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Костя'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Костя'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Олег'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Саша']
]

date_by_users = defaultdict(list)
for dt, user in array1:
    date_by_users[dt.date()].append(user)

for d, users in date_by_users.items():
    print(d)
    for user, number in Counter(users).items():
        print(f'{user}: {number}')

    print()
```

Результат:

```
2020-10-27
Саша: 4
Костя: 2
Олег: 1

2020-10-28
Олег: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = {}
for date, name in array1:
    if date.date() not in result:
        result[date.date()] = {}
    result[date.date()][name] = result[date.date()].get(name, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Создай еще один уровень словаря и возьми дату за ключ:

```
{Дата : [имя1, имя2, имя3],  дата2 : [имя1, имя2, имя3]}
```

потом обработай по такому же принципу как делал до этого.

Например:

```
date_dict = {}
for i in array:
    if i[0] in date_dict:
        date_dict[i[0]].append(i[1]) 
    else:
        date_dict.update({i[0] : [i[1],  ]})
```

В итоге получится словарь, где каждой дате соответствует список с нужными именами. А там по циклу обрабатыааешь каждый ключ